# How Django validates form?

Tags: python, django

I have a little issue. For example, I have this view:

```
def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Not Successfully Created")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

Main problem: after redirect I have both messages (if and else at the same time). WHY?

Solution is:

```
... ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
elif form.errors:
    messages.error(request, "Not Successfully Created")
context = {
   "form": form,
   }
return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

But why I see both of messages when I redirect after success validation (1st variant)?

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/base.css" %}' />
    <style>
        {% block style %}{% endblock style %}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {% include "messages_display.html" %}
    <div class='container'>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

messages_display.html:

```
 {% if messages %}
    <div class='messages'>

    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{% if "html_safe" in message.tags %}{{ message|safe }}{% else %}{{ message }}{% endif %}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    </div>
{% endif %}
```

post_form.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
<h1>Form</h1>

<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Create Post' />
</form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: This isn't really about validation. Messages persist in the session until they're actually displayed; so are you displaying messages in post_form.html?

Comment: I'm going to edit question. Yes - I have base.html and extend it in post_form.html.

Comment: MAYBE??? form.is_valid() is always False as default value. So, when I open post_form I always go to 'else' until I pass a valid data?

Comment: solved:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650104/stopping-django-messages-from-showing-error-message-and-success-message-at-once

Comment: Well, that's one solution. But a better one is to properly separate the POST and GET cases, following the pattern shown in the docs rather than this `request.POST or None` stuff.